# How to draw circle in rectangle using Java awt image

Tags: java, octave, producer-consumer

I have the image of a circle of size 256 x 256. The circle can be created by using a function B(i,j). By using a Java producer and consumer model, how can I create a java program to draw the circle?

[image: Circle in square]

The code in this image is using the octave code.

Comment: what do you want to `consume`??

Comment: i want draw the circle using java produce and consumer model....i have post an circle image on my question....actually i'm new in java, so this is my first basic testing and initiative to learn more about java.

Comment: it has nothing to do with producer consumer so far.

Comment: ok maybe i'm new on this

Comment: for a first step check the actual tag description: *The Producer-Consumer Problem (also known as the bounded-buffer problem) is a classical example of a multi-process synchronization problem.* - that has nothing do do with your current code and setup.

Comment: sorry, back to the topic, how to draw java circle in rectangle according the image that i send?

Comment: you probably should create a different question for that topic, link the image again, show your code and try to omit the consumer-producer-wording.

Comment: how to show code in this comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Java Swing GUI I created.

[image: Image of a circle]

I created (or produced) the image in the CreateImage class.  I used the code in your problem image, except I didn't take the square root.  Comparing the squares of the numbers was faster.

I drew (or consumed) the image on a JPanel.  I'm not going to explain the Swing code in great detail.  I wrote what I needed to write to display the image.

Here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawImage implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawImage());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Image image = new CreateImage(256, 256, 80).createImage();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image of a circle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new DrawingPanel(256, 256, image));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1584647402715684757L;

        private Image image;

        public DrawingPanel(int width, int height, Image image) {
            this.image = image;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }

    }

    public class CreateImage {

        private int width;
        private int height;
        private int radius;

        public CreateImage(int width, int height, int radius) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public Image createImage() {
            int circleRadiusSquared = radius * radius;

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                int idist = i - width / 2;
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                    int jdist = j - height / 2;
                    int distSquared = idist * idist + jdist * jdist;
                    if (distSquared < circleRadiusSquared) {
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    g.drawLine(i, j, i, j);
                }
            }

            g.dispose();

            return image;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, I've done some code, but it's different from you.

` dist = Math.pow(((Math.pow((j - 128), 2)) + (Math.pow((i - 128), 2))), 0.5);`

Comment: @joe: You're taking the square root, but otherwise, your equation is mathematically the same as my equation.  Squaring a number is the same as multiplying a number times itself.